# How to reconstruct 33-byte compressed NIST P-256 public key from 33 bytes?

Tags: android, kotlin, cryptography, bouncycastle, ecdsa

Supposed that the 33 bytes encoded Public Key can be created like this:

```
Security.addProvider(provider)
val generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA")
val ecSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256r1")
generator.initialize(ecSpec)
val keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair()
val privateKey = keyPair.private as ECPrivateKey
val publicKey = keyPair.public as ECPublicKey
val publicEncoded = publicKey.q.getEncoded(true)
```

How can I reconstruct it again on the other side (when I am having only the 33 bytes sent from here)?

I was trying below code:

```
val publicKey =KeyFactory.getInstance("EC").generatePublic(X509EncodedKeySpec(publicEncoded))
```

But I guess this is totally wrong, as I am getting the:

> java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0c000079:ASN.1 encoding routines:OPENSSL_internal:HEADER_TOO_LONG

I was trying also:

```
val generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA")
val ecPublicKey = generator
        .generatePublic(X509EncodedKeySpec((publicEncoded))) as ECPublicKey
```

But the error is:

> java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: encoded key spec not recognised

How to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
import org.bouncycastle.jce.ECNamedCurveTable
import org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECPublicKeySpec

fun publicKeyFromCompressed(compressedPublicKey: ByteArray): PublicKey {
    val ecSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256r1")
    val point = ecSpec.curve.decodePoint(compressedPublicKey)
    val publicKeySpec = ECPublicKeySpec(point, ecSpec)
    val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDSA")
    val publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec)
    return publicKey
}
```

Comment: You'd need to properly convert `point` and `ecSpec` since the types returned by `ECNamedCurveTable` are not compatible.

Comment: @Kiskae There is no need for conversion as long as you use the Bouncy Castle versions of the classes instead of the jce versions.

Answer (score 2):

The primary problem is that your `publicEncoded` is not an encoded public key, but an encoded `ECPoint` (`publicKey.q`).
This means you need to first reconstruct the point and then provide the appropriate curve to reconstruct the key to obtain the correct [`ECPublicKeySpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/spec/ECPublicKeySpec.html).

1. First re-obtain the chosen curve spec with `ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256r1")`. You can then use `ecSpec.curve.decodePoint(publicEncoded)` to reconstruct the BC `ECPoint` instance.
2. Turn the BouncyCastle `ECNamedCurveParameterSpec` into the `java.security.spec.ECParameterSpec` and the BouncyCastle `ECPoint` into the java `java.security.spec.ECPoint`. Then construct the appropriate `ECPublicKeySpec` which can then be used by the `ECDSA` key generator to recreate the complete `PublicKey`.

References:

- [`ECPoint.getEncoded()`](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonah/lcrypto/org/bouncycastle/math/ec/ECPoint.html#getEncoded()) / [`ECCurve.decodePoint(byte[])`](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonah/lcrypto/org/bouncycastle/math/ec/ECCurve.html#decodePoint(byte[]))
- [`ECNamedCurveParameterSpec`](http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonah/bc/org/bouncycastle/jce/spec/ECNamedCurveParameterSpec.html) / [`ECPublicKeySpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/spec/ECParameterSpec.html)
- [`ECPublicKeySpec(ECPoint, ECParameterSpec)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/spec/ECPublicKeySpec.html)

Comment: Maybe you can help me again here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53764831/how-to-construct-private-key-from-generated-previously-ecdsa-key-pair